# Can't use GPU on Google Colab for tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run my notebook using a GPU on Google Colab, but it doesn't provide me a GPU, however when I run the notebook with tensorflow 1.15.0, the GPU is available.

```
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

gives the output
`'/device:GPU:0'`
for tensorflow 1.15.0

But when I do the same with tensorflow 2.0.0 the function returns `''`.

Comment: Have you enabled GPU in hardware acceleration?

Comment: @thisisjaymehta Yes I have enabled the GPU in hardware acceleration and that's the function returns '/device:GPU:0' for tensorflow 1.15.0

Comment: Try uninstalling all old tensorflow version and install tensorflow-gpu

Comment: @thisisjaymehta still the same result.

Comment: Try upgrading CUDA to latest version

Answer (score 7):

I solved installing in google colab

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

and

```
!pip install tf-nightly
```

So now  `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`, the output is `/device:GPU:0`
But, TensorFlow automatically upgrade its version to `2.1.0-dev20191120`

Answer (score 5):

try

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug related to 2.0 being incompatible with a recent CUDA 10.1 upgrade on Colab.

The relevant GitHub issue to follow is:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/864

Answer (score 0):

According to https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb#scrollTo=oM_8ELnJq_wd

You'll need to enable GPUs for the notebook:

1. Navigate to Edit→Notebook Settings
2. select GPU from the Hardware Accelerator drop-dow